# mod_rewrite specific variables

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite

I know how to mod_rewrite this URL :

```
folder/example.php?var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3&var4=value4
```

To :

```
folder/value1/value2/value3/value4
```

By doing this :

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /folder/example.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L]
```

But I want to convert URL so that it contains one variable only like this :

```
folder/value1
```

OR even :

```
folder/example.php?var1=value1
```

value1 is unique = no duplicate URLs

Is there any method to achieve this ?

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking for here.  What do you mean by you want to "convert" the URL? Are you saying that you want something like `folder/value1` to redirect to something like `/folder/example.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4`?

Comment: @MikeBrant YES that is what i want to say. sorry for my bad grammer

Comment: If that is that case, you might need to look at using logic in your application to do this, rather than hoping that Apache can handle this.  You are getting more into the concept of request routing at this point, where Apache might directly such a URI to a specific script, but the specific script would need to be able to understand how to derive meaning from the URI.

Comment: Do all your routing in PHP, one rule is sufficient e.g: pass everything `^(.*)$`, otherwise it will eventually become an unmaintainable mess of rewrite rules, **been there done that**.

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè  could you explain more please. I have searched for routing in PHP but cannot understand how i will use it to meet my request

Answer (score 0):

Specify if each section is required or not, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([0-9]{4}?)/?([0-9]{2}?)/?([0-9]{2}?)/?([a-z0-9\-]+?)$ /folder/example.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L]
```

Comment: something went wrong . this does NOT work. i don't know why ?

Comment: Updated answer; you may want to handle this request in your PHP file, however.